# Unable to create a records using oci_dns_rrset with multiple rdata in terraform

Tags: terraform

I tried loop for items { } section but its not working . I am able to create a hosted zones and records under it but one address is able to assign to rdata. Below is the code

```
hosted_zones = {
  "test.poc.oci.io" = {
    "*.testRecord." = {
      records = ["1.2.3.4", "1.2.3.7"]
    }

    "*." = {
      records = ["1.2.3.5", "1.2.3.6"]
    }
  }
}

module "hosted_zones" {
  source = "./hosted_zones"
  for_each = var.hosted_zones
  zone = each.key
  records = each.value
  # rdatas = each.value.records
  compartment_ocid = "ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaar2rh2jq"
}


resource "oci_dns_zone" "zone" {
  compartment_id = var.compartment_ocid
  name           = var.zone
  zone_type      = "PRIMARY"
}

resource "oci_dns_rrset" "records" {

# Here I want to create a record with multiple rdata
  for_each        = var.records
  zone_name_or_id = oci_dns_zone.zone.name
  domain          = "${each.key}${var.zone}"
  rtype           = try(each.value.type, "A")

  # Dont know how to loop so that it will create items twice with rdata 
  items {
    #Required
    domain = "${each.key}${var.zone}"
    rdata  = each.value.records[0] 
    rtype  = try(each.value.type, "A")
    ttl = 60
    }
}
```

I tried loop for items { } section but it's not working. I am able to create a hosted zones and records under it but one address is able to assign to rdata.

Comment: reference line no 15 to 28 https://github.com/oracle/terraform-provider-oci/blob/master/examples/dns/private/rrset/rrset.tf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use the `dynamic` block:

```
resource "oci_dns_rrset" "records" {

# Here I want to create a record with multiple rdata
  for_each        = var.records
  zone_name_or_id = oci_dns_zone.zone.name
  domain          = "${each.key}${var.zone}"
  rtype           = try(each.value.type, "A")

  # Dont know how to loop so that it will create items twice with rdata 
  dynamic "items" {
    for_each = each.value.records
    content {
      domain = "${each.key}${var.zone}"
      rdata  = items.value 
      rtype  = try(each.value.type, "A")
      ttl = 60
    }
  }
}
```

Unlike `for_each` which can work with maps and sets only, `dynamic` blocks can work with lists as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's working but instead rdata  = items.key. I have changed it to rdata  = items.value

Comment: Fixed it in the answer as well.